# Div inside a td cross browser issues

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside of a td that renders fine in Chrome and Firefox but whose height is too short in IE11. 
Here is a fiddle which illustrates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/random_user_9999/9BXsc/

and here is the html:

```
<table class="dlts">
<tr class="dltrs">
<td class="dltds"><asp:Label ID="Label1" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="medium" runat="server" Text="One" ></asp:Label></td>
<td class="dltds"><asp:Label ID="_lbl" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="medium" runat="server" Text="Two" ></asp:Label></td>
<td class="dltds"><div id="adiv" class="ytdc" runat = "server"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and inside my css file:

```
dlts //table style
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
.dltrs //row style
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
}
.dltds //td style
{
width:33%; text-align:center; height:40px; border:1px solid black;margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;
}
.ytdc //div style
{
height:50%; text-align: center; width:80%;display:inline-block;position:relative;
background-color:#e5c732;border-radius: 2px;-webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52), inset -2px 2px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.52); 
-moz-box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52), inset -2px 2px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.52);
box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52), inset -2px 2px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

The td which has the div does not render as I thought it would in IE11 -- it is too short. I tried using a span instead of a div (no luck) and tried different td styles. Changing the display style on the td gave me the correct height but put extra padding in-between table cells. Does anyone know why using the table-cell display doesn`t work as expected in IE, and what a possible workaround might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `margins` and `paddings`, although they were set to `0`.

And i removed the `border-collapse` and added `cellspacing="0"` to the table.

This jsfiddle works in my IE 11 and Chrome browser. The only thing that is now a little different is that the vertical lines between cells are a bit 'bolder' then the edges. Check for yourself.

If this is a problem for you i'll look for another solution (it doesnt bother me though).

http://jsfiddle.net/9BXsc/11/

Kind Regards

Comment: Looks great, thanks. I also just figured out I could make it work by changing the height from a percentage to a fixed number; i.e. 20 px (which sounds like IE is buggy in that regard). The border issue is not a problem as I can just set different styles for each td where I leave the border on one side blank.